# On-premises setup incomplete for Azure Hybrid connection

Tags: azure

I am trying to set up a Hybrid connection to my on=premises SQL Database.
My default instance of SQL Server 2008R2 is on port 1433.
In the classic portal,  I have set up a biztalk service using the Free Preview Edition, South East Asia.  Clicking on this, and entering Hybrid Connections Preview, I have attempted to set up a Hybrid Connection Name.
Using my computer's name as the Host Name and Port 1433.
However the Status column states "On-premises setup incomplete"
I have run the On-Premises set up several times.

My On-premises machine is Windows 7

I have also logged the issue at [Microsoft support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97de59e2-3021-427b-a4f5-3990d28db7ab/hybrid-connection-onpremise-setup-incomplete?forum=azurebiztalksvcs)